# How do I change the home/back button icon in the actionbar in Titanium using native code?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop, titanium-sdk, hyperloop

I would like to change the back/home button icon in Titanium. I am able to do this using the Theme.

However I would like to change the icon at runtime after I apply the theme. The actionbar in titanium does not have any property or method to change the icon. [Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar). So I am using the hyperloop (native code) to change the icon, but unfortunately I am not able to access the actionbar.

Here is my view

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <ActionBar id="actionbar" displayHomeAsUp="true" homeButtonEnabled="true"></ActionBar>
        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

My code

```
import AppCompatActivity from 'android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity';
const activity = new AppCompatActivity(Ti.Android.currentActivity);
activity.getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(Titanium.Android.R.drawable.notificacion);
```

And the error

```
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,434] /alloy/controllers/index.js:69
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:   activity.getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(Titanium.Android.R.drawable.notificacionmas);
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:                           ^
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler: TypeError: activity.getActionBar(...).setHomeAsUpIndicator is not a function
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at new Controller (/alloy/controllers/index.js:69:27)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Object.exports.createController (/alloy.js:428:10)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at /app.js:22:7
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module._runScript (ti:/module.js:608:9)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.load (ti:/module.js:107:7)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.loadJavascriptText (ti:/module.js:453:9)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.loadAsFile (ti:/module.js:508:15)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.loadAsFileOrDirectory (ti:/module.js:425:20)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.require (ti:/module.js:255:17)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     at Module.global.Module.require (/ti.main.js:11435:34)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.nativeRunModule(Native Method)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Runtime.doRunModule(V8Runtime.java:162)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime.runModule(KrollRuntime.java:207)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLaunchActivity.loadScript(TiLaunchActivity.java:99)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiRootActivity.loadScript(TiRootActivity.java:480)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiLaunchActivity.onResume(TiLaunchActivity.java:183)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     org.appcelerator.titanium.TiRootActivity.onResume(TiRootActivity.java:499)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1446)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7939)
[ERROR] TiExceptionHandler:     android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4195)
[ERROR] V8Exception: Exception occurred at /alloy/controllers/index.js:69: Uncaught TypeError: activity.getActionBar(...).setHomeAsUpIndicator is not a function
```

### Note

I believe this question is not a duplicate, since it is related to Titanium and not native Android.

Comment: I have an example that uses a custom XML layout where I specify the Actionbar and access it via code: https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.collapsingToolbarLayout if that is an option for you you could try to change the icon there

Comment: I'm having the same issue right now. Looks like Hyperloop expects you to use android.app.Activity, even though Titanium uses the support library (at least before 9.0.0), and the Activity doesn't return an ActionBar with getActionBar(). Really frustrating that Titanium just doesn't expose the setHomeAsUpIndicator() method. Both setIcon and setLogo do not set the actual button drawable.

Comment: FYI I tried using android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and getSupportActionBar(). It returns an ActionBar instance, but doesn't seem to be tied to the actual ActionBar.

Comment: @cr0ybo I got tired and gave up. I just needed this in one screen. The client wanted to replace the home button with the notification button. So I hid the actionbar and put a view that look liked an action bar.

Comment: @miga Thanks for your help. I used some of your code but unfortunately I was not able to set the icon. I guess I was passing the reference to the drawable in a wrong way.

Comment: @Searock I've added an answer with a full example. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated my Hyperloop example at https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.collapsingToolbarLayout

It's using a custom back icon in the "collapsing toolbar" example screen.
I've added a icon xml:

```xml
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFF00"
        android:pathData="M16,11c1.66,0 2.99,-1.34 2.99,-3S17.66,5 16,5c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3zm-8,0c1.66,0 2.99,-1.34 2.99,-3S9.66,5 8,5C6.34,5 5,6.34 5,8s1.34,3 3,3zm0,2c-2.33,0 -7,1.17 -7,3.5V19h14v-2.5c0,-2.33 -4.67,-3.5 -7,-3.5zm8,0c-0.29,0 -0.62,0.02 -0.97,0.05 1.16,0.84 1.97,1.97 1.97,3.45V19h6v-2.5c0,-2.33 -4.67,-3.5 -7,-3.5z"/>
</vector>
```

and assigning it with

```js
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(resIDFromString("ic_action_users", "drawable"));
```

(https://github.com/m1ga/hyperloop.collapsingToolbarLayout/blob/master/app/controllers/second.js#L44)

The full example is inside the repo

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need of Hyperloop for this.

You can communicate with the actionBar using the `activity` https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android.Activity

Then you can fetch the `actionBar` from the activity, and then change the icon using the `icon` property of the `actionBar`

Make sure to do this only after the window has triggered the `open` event though.

```
window.addEvenListener('open', e => {
  var actionbar = window.activity.actionBar;
  actionbar.icon = '/images/upicon.png'; 
});
```

Comment: This changes the application icon and not the back button. This could have worked for me if I just had to display an icon and not interact with the icon. Thanks. +1